# Mount Windows smb shares on a Mac using Python

Tags: macos, python-3.x, mount, smb

I would like create a python script that mounts a Windows smb share on a Mac then copies data to it. I am falling at the first hurdle, having problems with mounting the share. It should be really easy but I can't get it to work. I have trawled the internet and have a few clues:

```
mount -t smbfs //user@server/sharename share
```

This doesn't work but I have seen another solution that uses the os module for the mount command:

```
import os
os.system("mount -t smbfs //user@server/sharename share")
```

But this doesn't work either.

I have also read about creating a local mount point for the remote share to mount to. Is this true? And how would I go about this?

Many thanks for any insights

All the best

John

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is mounting a volume in the operating system and is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. Better suited for [apple.se] or [su] instead. Mounting the volume is an OS problem; if you have problems when you get to the python script to copy the files, we can help.

Comment: @Ken White. Thank you for you comments. I have re-phrased the question to make it less ambiguous and will also post it to the other forums. Appreciate your help. All the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I have figured it out:

```
import os
directory = "/Users/user.name/foldername"
if not os.path.exists(directory): os.makedirs(directory)
os.system("mount_smbfs //user.name:password@server/servershare ~/foldername")
```

This will check whether a local folder called foldername exists and create it if doesn't. It will then mount the smb share into it using a defined username/password.

Answer (score 0):

An important thing to note is that the directory variable defined up there needs to be either absolute, or in relative reference, it can't use the ~ to denote the home drive.

Eg. This would be invalid and would cause os.path.exists() to function incorrectly:

`directory = "~/user.name/foldername"`

A late addition I know, but I thought it was worth mentioning since it tripped me up when trying to use this. I would've made this a comment but I don't have the rep to be able to do so. Thanks :)